# LaTeX Error: file 'breakcites.sty' not found on Fedora 24/25?

Tags: linux, linuxfedora

I am using Fedora 24  and have installed all possible TeX packages

`sudo dnf install tex\*
 sudo dnf install texlive-\*`

etc...

I am using TeX Maker 4.5. How  can I solve the 'breakcites.sty' not found problem?
I tried to install some rpms found [here](https://pkgs.org/download/texlive-breakcites)
but with no success. 
I downloaded  a breakcites.tzr.xz but could not know how to include the sty file that is included inside.

Any suggestions on how to install this on Fedora 24 / Fedora 25 (I have another machine with Fedora 25)?

General answers if possible that works for Fedora and other distros  might be helpful and well appreciated in case someone has the same problem for other distros. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Put the sty-file in the same folder as your project. This has to be done for all projects using that package. Alternatively add it to your local textree and recache that (on Arch the command is `mktexlsr`). This way it's usable for every tex-project on your machine.

Comment: Thanks Skillmon. Can you show me  how to add that so that it works on all projects not only the current one like how to "add it to your local textree and recache that (on Arch the command is mktexlsr" on Fedora terminal if you know that. Even the full procedure on Arch Linux terminal is a good start.  Please. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Take a look at the arch-wiki for the procedure. I don't know whether this is completely the same on Fedora. Link: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TeX_Live#Install_.sty_files

Comment: Just for reference, on Ubuntu, you need `sudo apt install texlive-bibtex-extra` to get `breakcites.sty`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for Fedora 24 thanks to the help provided by  Skillmon comment.

I installed the Fedora Rawhide x86_64 package: "texlive-breakcites-svn21014-32.fc26.1.noarch.rpm". 
I did provide [the link](https://pkgs.org/download/texlive-breakcites) in the question.

```
sudo dnf install PathToRPMFile/texlive-breakcites-svn21014-32.fc26.1.noarch.rpm
```

Then I restarted the system.

In the TeX Live Arch Linux Wiki provided thankfully by Skillmon [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TeX_Live#Install_.sty_files)
I issued on my Fedora terminal (with sudo) the following commands:

```
sudo mktexlsr
```

and also this command

```
sudo texhash
```

This have done some refreshing of directory indexes (even that did not happen after the system restart for unknown reason!!). This makes the breakcites package work on all future LaTeX projects and thus solved the error.

Comment: You do not need to restart the system after installation of a TeX package.

Comment: Thanks Boris. I think the restart is not needed as you said and did not do anything. The refreshing of indexes normally sort things out.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question pops up on search engines even if you don't specify you're using Fedora:

On Ubuntu you can get `breakcites.sty` using

```
sudo apt install texlive-bibtex-extra
```

as already mentioned by Albert in the comments.